# jQuery hint plugin in combination with ASP.NET MVC3 client side validation

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

By jQuery hint plugin i mean a plugin which shows a line of guiding text like "Enter your name here ..." inside an input.

When i use such a plugin in combination with jQuery asp.net mvc clientside validation it will validate against the hint when it is actually empty.

Im wondering if there is already a plugin which plays nice with the jQuery asp.net mvc clientside validation, meaning that it either clears the input of the hint on validation or simply ignores the contents of the input if its equal to its hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took the time to create a plugin myself. This plugin doesnt show the description/hint inside the input but on top of it.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Description